# Is it possible to get the name of the author of a page post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

From the documentation it seems like '{post_id}/?fields=from' should return the author of a page post, but it just returns the page that posted it.

I want the page user that posted it, which you can see if you look at the posts on the website. ie "Published by User name"

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post

it says that from provides "Information (name and id) about the Profile that created the Post. If you read this field with a user access token, it returns only the current user."

My reading is that should provide the user name/id but when I use it I just get the page name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `admin_creator` field.

Quote from the same page you already referred to:

> The admin creator of a Page post. If the Page has only one admin, no data will be returned. Requires a Page Access Token and the `business_management` permission.